# JSON: Link to item of array

Tags: arrays, json

My JSON:

```
[{"status":"success","id":1,"title":"title1","content":"test"},
{"status":"success","id":2,"title":"title2","content":"test2"},
{"status":"success","id":3,"title":"title3","content":"test3"},
{"status":"success","id":4,"title":"title4","content":"test4"}]
```

I have the following success-function inside of my Ajax Request:

```
function(response){

    response.forEach(function(data) {

 $('#suche').append('<li id="post_id_' + data.id + '" ><a href="#detailedpost" class="item-link item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">' + data.title + '</div></div></a></li>');

    })//foreach end

 }
```

Now I want to show the content of the item with id 3 for example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#post_id_'  + data.id, function(){

$('#postcontent').append(data.content);
});
```

How can I assign the correct content "test3" for this ID?

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: i get the wrong content

Comment: Which one do you get? What is the content of `data`?

Comment: Did you put the click handler code inside your `.forEach` block?  It actually looks ok to me.  What sort of issues are you having where it's not working?

Comment: Yes but I get the results of all items

Comment: Okay I think its because of my functions. Each click generates one more content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `response` is what you posted

```
[{"status":"success","id":1,"title":"title1","content":"test"},
{"status":"success","id":2,"title":"title2","content":"test2"},
{"status":"success","id":3,"title":"title3","content":"test3"},
{"status":"success","id":4,"title":"title4","content":"test4"}];
```

The following code should display the content associated with each element when you click on it.

```
function(response){
   response.forEach(function(data) {

       $('#suche').append('<li id="post_id_' + data.id + '" ><a href="#detailedpost" class="item-link item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">' + data.title + '</div></div></a></li>');

       $(document).on('click', '#post_id_'  + data.id, function(){
           $('#postcontent').html(data.content);   //replace content instead of appending
       });
   })//foreach end
}
```